# Liquibase rollback silently fails when using copy of changelog file

Tags: java, spring, liquibase, rollback

I am trialling liquibase at the moment and am having an issue with rollbacks in a very specific scenario.

I have implemented a Spring listener bean to start liquibase from within my web application with the idea being that to deploy the latest web code and database backend you simply deploy the web code, start the app, and liquibase will run in any required database changes. (the changelog files reside within the web app)

So far so good. This all works nicely. The issue comes when trying to do a rollback. So the scenario I'm trying to imlpement is that, to rollback the application version I should simply deploy the old version of the web app (with the old versions of the changelog files) and I perform a roll back to the previous state of the database as well.

This has required capturing a rollback tag in the application property file and copying the changelog to a location that the web server can access for running the rollback (as the changelog in the app will no longer have the change sets to rollback if I'm deploying an older version).

The issue is that the rollback step does not occur although no errors are thrown. I'm suspecting that when liwuibase attempts to rollback the changes from the copied changelog on the web server that somehow the MD5 checksum is different so it does not roll them back.

Here's an example changelog. I'm supplying a logicalFilePath and also trying to use validCheckSum to ensure there are no checksum failures. Howver, the rollback still does not occur.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd"
logicalFilePath="/liquibase/changelogs/sprint2/changelog.xml">


<changeSet id="5" author="Craig" runOnChange="true">
    <validCheckSum>*</validCheckSum>
    <comment>liquibase_proc.sql</comment>
    <sqlFile path="liquibase_proc.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"
        endDelimiter="\nGO" />
    <rollback>
        <sql>drop procedure liquibase_proc</sql>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="BUILD-1.2" author="build-auto">
    <validCheckSum>*</validCheckSum>
    <tagDatabase tag="BUILD-1.2" />
</changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Anyone got any ideas? FYI the copied changelog is on a unix box where as the original is on windows, could this have an effect?

Comment: Can you set the liquibase log level to debug and include the log file generated?

Comment: Ok so I figured out the issue. I was attempting to alter the changelog location of the Liquibase instance from one location to another. So effectively, if running in new changes then use the changelog within the web app, if running a rollback then use the changelog on the webserver. However, trying to change the changelog location of the Liquibase instance was not working as expected. The solution was to have two separate Liquibase instances, one for each changelog location.

Answer (score 0):

See comment above. solution was to use multiple instances of Liquibase class